# How to properly drill new holes in metal door for installing new door hinges?

Tags: doors, metal, hinges

I need to replace some old door hinges and the current hinges only have 2 of the 4 holes drilled. I am installing 4x4 self closing hinges and want to have all the screws installed. Problem is I did a dry run on a different door and the machined screws don’t pull the hinge to the door tightly, they get to a certain point and just spin. Obviously I don’t know what I’m doing. I’d like to know what equipment I need, what size screws, what size bits, the works. The door is a residential door, most likely hollow with insulation on the inside.

Comment: Is this a hollow steel door (commercial style) or a steel-wrapped wooden door? Commercial-style doors have heavy plates welded into the structure at the hinge points and will be tapped for machine-thread screws. You can't expect sheet-metal screws in light metal to carry that dynamic load for any length of time. Please [revise your post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/175478/edit) to add detail about the door.

Comment: Updated to mention it is a residential metal wrapped door.

Comment: What are "machined screws"? Do you mean _machine-thread screws_? Obviously those wouldn't be ideal in wood. Use wood screws of around #12.